# amqp-appender not receiving messages

Tags: logging, spring-amqp

I have a simple test app using the AmqpAppender to log messages. 
When I run my app I can see the console based message get written out, but the AMQP one doesn't. More concerning to me is that I don't see any output from the appender at all to indicate that it might have a problem. I have tested with invalid exchange names, as well as with the rabbitmq server turned off (testing against my local box) but nothing ever shows up.

Shouldn't I at least get an error in System.err when it can't find the host for the appender?

I am inintializing my webapp using the WebApplicationInitializer, but I don't have any other spring-beans defined for Rabbit as currently only the logger is using it.

Here is my log4j.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
```

```
<appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
    <param name="Target" value="System.out" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5p %c{1} - %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>

<!-- Complete Logger -->
<appender name="amqp" class="org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.log4j.AmqpAppender">
    <param name="host" value="www.yousuck.io" />
    <param name="port" value="5672" />
    <param name="virtualHost" value="platform" />
    <param name="username" value="username" />
    <param name="password" value="password" />
    <param name="exchangeName" value="testExchange" />
    <param name="exchangeType" value="topic" />
    <param name="routingKeyPattern" value="test" />
    <param name="applicationId" value="ErrorsAppenderTest" />
    <param name="declareExchange" value="true" />
    <param name="durable" value="true" />
    <param name="contentType" value="text/plain" />
    <param name="senderPoolSize" value="2" />
    <param name="maxSenderRetries" value="30" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5p %c{1} - %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>

<root>
    <!-- <level value="debug" /> -->
    <priority value="debug" />
    <appender-ref ref="amqp" />
    <appender-ref ref="console" />
</root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

What am I missing here that is causing this to not even initialize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you sure you're picking up the right log4j.xml (use `-Dlog4j.debug=true`) then you are probably not waiting long enough. The retries are exponentially backed off; with max retries at 30 it will take many minutes before the error is logged (the last retry waits 30 seconds, the next to last 29, etc etc). Reduce the retries and you should see:

```
log4j:ERROR Could not send log message This is an INFO message with properties after 1 retries
org.springframework.amqp.AmqpIOException: java.net.UnknownHostException: junk
```

(this from one of our test cases with a bad host name).

Some errors (such as this) should probably be deemed as fatal rather than retried; feel free to open up a [JIRA 'Improvement' Issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/AMQP).

Comment: I had forgotten the quirks of using log4j jn jboss which comlicates which log4j is used.